# PNG 500 error - Save operation failed

Tags: assets

I have just discovered that all Craft sites on our server no longer let users upload PNG files and I'm struggling to find the issue / fix.

The craft.log simply says 'Save operation failed' and the JS console mentions 500 internal server error.

I've tried various PNG formats, and weirdly other systems on our server using Imagemagick are running fine.

Anyone had a similar issue / suggestions for debugging?

Answer (score 2):

If other image formats are working fine, then maybe check that you have Imagick installed and enabled on the server.

Eg.

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick php5-imagick
sudo service apache2 reload
```

If you're on a shared host then either consult their knowledge base or contact support to check for Imagick availability.

Some servers/hosts only have the GD library installed by default, which isn't so good with PNG files.

Comment: ImageMagick is installed and running, listed within Craft utils and phpinfo, and works fine within other CMS/Frameworks.
Just rebooted server too without any change...

Comment: Plus PNGs were being uploaded fine a couple of months ago, the only thing that's changed is the updates to Craft.

Comment: Just tried commenting out the line as suggested here and it works http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/6862/png-upload-problem-core-hack-issue-in-imagick

Comment: I'm glad you got it sorted.

Comment: Hacking the vendor lib seems a bit extreme… I guess I'll ping support@ and see what they say. Thanks for your comments :)

Comment: @TomCarwardine Thanks for the update. This definitely sounds like a bug, hopefully P&T can help you sort it out (and fix it for a future release).